# Receiving nested JSON objects in django

Tags: javascript, python, django, json

What is the best way to accept a nested json object in a django view ?

The request

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'results/' + self.id + '/',
   contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: JSON.stringify(values),
   dataType:"json",
   ...
```

`values` is a javascript dictionary object.

```
Object {Cart: Array[2], Di: "5"}
  Cart: Array[2]
    0: Object
      N: 1
      PR: 0.75
      __proto__: Object
    1: Object
      N: "2"
      PR: 2.5
      __proto__: Object
  length: 2
  __proto__: Array[0]
  Di: "5"
```

The view

```
def do_something(request,pid):
    print json.loads(request.body)
```

This is the raw post data

```
{"Cart":["{\"PR\":4,\"N\":1}","{\"PR\":1.2,\"N\":\"2\"}"],"Di":"5"}
```

The problem is that `json.loads` leaves the inner dicts in the `Cart` array as unicode objects.

I've tried using [jsonpickle](http://jsonpickle.github.io/#api-reference) and the old `simplejson` but i'm getting the same results.

This seem pretty basic - Is there a simple solution for this ?

**EDIT**

After reading your posts I understand it might be a client side issue but I'm still stringifying the json data only once in the ajax call.

This is how i generate `values`

The basic case - simple Dict

```
self.serialized_value = function() {
        if (self.value()) {
           var d = {}
           d[self.name] = self.value();
           return (d);
        }
    };
```

For object containing several parameters

```
self.get_serialized_values = function() {
        var values = {};
        $.map(self.parameters(), function(p) {
            $.extend(values, p.serialized_value());
        });
        return values;
    };
```

For object that contain other objects

```
 self.serialized_value = function() {
        var child_data = [];
        $.each(self.items() , function(k,v) { 
            child_data.push(v.get_serialized_values());
        });
        var d = {}
        d[self.name] = child_data;
        return (d);
    };
```

And finally, `JSON.stringify` is applied only in the ajax call

```
..
data: JSON.stringify(self.get_serialized_values())
..
```

Where in the code is the json being stringified twice ?

Comment: json.loads can handle nested objects, I guess it was not serialized correctly on the client side. are you sure you called JSON.stringify on the object as it is you posted, and you didn't serialize its nested parts manually before you serialized the whole object itself?

Comment: The raw post data is embedding JSON in JSON. Ick! The `Cart` list consists of two strings that  themselves need decoding. What in heavens name is producing this?

Comment: I added my code for generating Cart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an issue on the client side. You are serializing twice:

**good**

```
var x = { PR: 4, N: 1 };
var cart = { Cart: [x] };
JSON.stringify(cart);
```

**bad** (produces your issue)

```
var x = { PR: 4, N: 1 };
var cart = { Cart: [JSON.stringify(x)] };
JSON.stringify(cart);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your posted data contains *doubly* encoded JSON data:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = {"Cart":["{\"PR\":4,\"N\":1}","{\"PR\":1.2,\"N\":\"2\"}"],"Di":"5"}
>>> data['Cart']
['{"PR":4,"N":1}', '{"PR":1.2,"N":"2"}']
>>> data['Cart'][0]
'{"PR":4,"N":1}'
>>> json.loads(data['Cart'][0])
{u'PR': 4, u'N': 1}
>>> json.loads(data['Cart'][1])
{u'PR': 1.2, u'N': u'2'}
```

Whatever produced this structure first encoded each `Cart` entry, then encoded the whole structure. Try to avoid this, as decoding now requires *two* steps.

In Python, you can repair this with:

```
def do_something(request,pid):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    data['Cart'] = [json.loads(d) for d in data['Cart']]
```

but ideally, you should fix the JS code that creates the nested structure.